# CookieManagerにセットしたCookieの生存期限が知りたい。

Tags: android, cookie

Androidアプリを起動した時Cookieが残っていたら直接WebViewを表示して
残っていなかったらログイン画面を表示させようとしています。

CookieManagerにセットしたCookieの生存期間は同じCookieをブラウザで保存した時と同じでしょうか？
また、今回の場合はSharedPreferencesかなにかに保存したほうが効果的でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ログインしてすぐ再起動とかでは
`CookieManager`がCookieをきちんと保存できていない(nullが返ってくる)ことに気づきました。
なので`SharedPreferences`かなにかに保存したほうがよいかもしれません。